# Barchart not working (Cannot resolve class .....charts.BarChart)

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

**build:gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.group10.chart"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

**build:gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!--Ui component for our bar chart-->
    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
        android:id="@+id/idBarChart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**I dont know what is missing but this line shows**
*Cannot resolve class com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart*

*What I tried*

1. Its an MPchart
2. I tried using graphview which works just perfect but want to use bar charts from my project and I am using Android Studio Articfox version

and thank you for helping me

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, and fixed it.
in the "settings.gradle"

add the following line into repositories

```
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

So it should look like this:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
         // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}
rootProject.name = "GraphViewExample"
include ':app'
```